# Why Chef do not find my files?

Tags: linux, centos, chef-infra, knife

I'm developing a `Ganglia` recipe in `Chef`.
Is very simple, I build four different configurations files, I already tried to use as `template`, but to keep it simple, I build these configuration files.

This is my recipe:

```rb
return if tagged?('norun::ganglia')

case node[:platform]
  when "ubuntu", "debian"
    pkg = "ganglia-monitor"
  when "redhat", "centos", "fedora"
    pkg = "ganglia-gmond"
end

package "#{pkg}" do
    action :install
end

cookbook_file "/etc/ganglia/gmond.conf" do
    owner "root"
    group "root"
    mode "0644"
    source "gmond/" + node['base']['dc'] + "/node/gmond.conf" 
end

# Adding ganglia-gmond as service
service "gmond" do
  supports :status => true,
           :restart => true
  action [ :enable, :start ]
end
```

And this is how my recipe is structured:

```
cookbooks/ganglia/
cookbooks/ganglia/files/default/gmond/* // I have others sub-folders here too
cookbooks/ganglia/files/default/gmond/diveo/node/gmond.conf
cookbooks/ganglia/recipes/default.rb
```

But when I tried to run my recipe, it gives the follow error:

```
[2013-05-14T14:23:38+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::FileNotFound: cookbook_file[/etc/ganglia/gmond.conf] (ganglia::default line 25) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::FileNotFound: Cookbook 'ganglia' (0.1.0) does not contain a file at any of these locations:
  files/centos-5.7/gmond/diveo/node/gmond.conf
  files/centos/gmond/diveo/node/gmond.conf
  files/default/gmond/diveo/node/gmond.conf

This cookbook _does_ contain: ['diveo/monitor/gmond.conf','diveo/node/gmond.conf','awsvir/monitor/gmond.conf','awsvir/node/gmond.conf','awssp/monitor/gmond.conf','awssp/node/gmond.conf','alog/monitor/gmond.conf','alog/node/gmond.conf']
```

Basically it says that I not have the file, but I do, in the right path, right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `node['base']['dc']` is a platform name, then [`cookbook_file`](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_cookbook_files.html) statement should look like

```rb
cookbook_file "/etc/ganglia/gmond.conf" do
    owner "root"
    group "root"
    mode "0644"
    source "gmond.conf"
end
```

and structure of your conf files should be like that

```
cookbooks/ganglia/
cookbooks/ganglia/files/default/gmond.conf
cookbooks/ganglia/files/centos-5.7/gmond.conf
...
```

And a little advice - use `template` instead of `cookbook_file`. One day you'll want to add some parameters to your `gmane.conf` anyway.

Also, here is a `cookbook_file` doc page from opscode.com -

Comment: Thank you Dmitri! About using template, I will create a post about it.

Comment: Post created Dmitri.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16550591/how-create-a-template-to-my-recipe-in-chef-for-two-different-configuration-files