# How create a template to my recipe in CHEF for two different configuration files?

Tags: templates, chef-infra

I have two different configuration files, to [Ganglia Monitoring](http://ganglia.sourceforge.net/) daemon, `gmond`.

The first (this configuration file came with ganglia-gmond-3.17, from `rpmforge` package):

```
/* This configuration is as close to 2.5.x default behavior as possible
   The values closely match ./gmond/metric.h definitions in 2.5.x */
globals {
  daemonize = yes
  setuid = yes
  user = ganglia
  debug_level = 0
  max_udp_msg_len = 1472
  mute = no
  deaf = yes
  allow_extra_data = yes
  host_dmax = 86400 /*secs */
  cleanup_threshold = 300 /*secs */
  gexec = no
  send_metadata_interval = 30 /*secs */
}

/*
 * The cluster attributes specified will be used as part of the <CLUSTER>
 * tag that will wrap all hosts collected by this instance.
 */
cluster {
  name = "DATAC1"
  owner = "Valter"
  latlong = "unspecified"
  url = ""
}

/* The host section describes attributes of the host, like the location */
host {
  location = "unspecified"
}

/* Feel free to specify as many udp_send_channels as you like.  Gmond
   used to only support having a single channel */
udp_send_channel {
  host = datac1.ganglia.valter.com
  port = 8660
  ttl = 1
}

/* You can specify as many udp_recv_channels as you like as well. */
udp_recv_channel {
  port = 8660
}

/* You can specify as many tcp_accept_channels as you like to share
   an xml description of the state of the cluster */
tcp_accept_channel {
  port = 8660
}

/* Each metrics module that is referenced by gmond must be specified and
   loaded. If the module has been statically linked with gmond, it does
   not require a load path. However all dynamically loadable modules must
   include a load path. */
modules {
  module {
    name = "core_metrics"
  }
  module {
    name = "cpu_module"
    path = "modcpu.so"
  }
  module {
    name = "disk_module"
    path = "moddisk.so"
  }
  module {
    name = "load_module"
    path = "modload.so"
  }
  module {
    name = "mem_module"
    path = "modmem.so"
  }
  module {
    name = "net_module"
    path = "modnet.so"
  }
  module {
    name = "proc_module"
    path = "modproc.so"
  }
  module {
    name = "sys_module"
    path = "modsys.so"
  }
}

include ('/etc/ganglia/conf.d/*.conf')

/* The old internal 2.5.x metric array has been replaced by the following
   collection_group directives.  What follows is the default behavior for
   collecting and sending metrics that is as close to 2.5.x behavior as
   possible. */

/* This collection group will cause a heartbeat (or beacon) to be sent every
   20 seconds.  In the heartbeat is the GMOND_STARTED data which expresses
   the age of the running gmond. */
collection_group {
  collect_once = yes
  time_threshold = 20
  metric {
    name = "heartbeat"
  }
}

/* This collection group will send general info about this host every
   1200 secs.
   This information doesn't change between reboots and is only collected
   once. */
collection_group {
  collect_once = yes
  time_threshold = 1200
  metric {
    name = "cpu_num"
    title = "CPU Count"
  }
  metric {
    name = "cpu_speed"
    title = "CPU Speed"
  }
  metric {
    name = "mem_total"
    title = "Memory Total"
  }
  /* Should this be here? Swap can be added/removed between reboots. */
  metric {
    name = "swap_total"
    title = "Swap Space Total"
  }
  metric {
    name = "boottime"
    title = "Last Boot Time"
  }
  metric {
    name = "machine_type"
    title = "Machine Type"
  }
  metric {
    name = "os_name"
    title = "Operating System"
  }
  metric {
    name = "os_release"
    title = "Operating System Release"
  }
  metric {
    name = "location"
    title = "Location"
  }
}

/* This collection group will send the status of gexecd for this host
   every 300 secs.*/
/* Unlike 2.5.x the default behavior is to report gexecd OFF. */
collection_group {
  collect_once = yes
  time_threshold = 300
  metric {
    name = "gexec"
    title = "Gexec Status"
  }
}

/* This collection group will collect the CPU status info every 20 secs.
   The time threshold is set to 90 seconds.  In honesty, this
   time_threshold could be set significantly higher to reduce
   unneccessary  network chatter. */
collection_group {
  collect_every = 20
  time_threshold = 90
  /* CPU status */
  metric {
    name = "cpu_user"
    value_threshold = "1.0"
    title = "CPU User"
  }
  metric {
    name = "cpu_system"
    value_threshold = "1.0"
    title = "CPU System"
  }
  metric {
    name = "cpu_idle"
    value_threshold = "5.0"
    title = "CPU Idle"
  }
  metric {
    name = "cpu_nice"
    value_threshold = "1.0"
    title = "CPU Nice"
  }
  metric {
    name = "cpu_aidle"
    value_threshold = "5.0"
    title = "CPU aidle"
  }
  metric {
    name = "cpu_wio"
    value_threshold = "1.0"
    title = "CPU wio"
  }
  /* The next two metrics are optional if you want more detail...
     ... since they are accounted for in cpu_system.
  metric {
    name = "cpu_intr"
    value_threshold = "1.0"
    title = "CPU intr"
  }
  metric {
    name = "cpu_sintr"
    value_threshold = "1.0"
    title = "CPU sintr"
  }
  */
}

collection_group {
  collect_every = 20
  time_threshold = 90
  /* Load Averages */
  metric {
    name = "load_one"
    value_threshold = "1.0"
    title = "One Minute Load Average"
  }
  metric {
    name = "load_five"
    value_threshold = "1.0"
    title = "Five Minute Load Average"
  }
  metric {
    name = "load_fifteen"
    value_threshold = "1.0"
    title = "Fifteen Minute Load Average"
  }
}

/* This group collects the number of running and total processes */
collection_group {
  collect_every = 80
  time_threshold = 950
  metric {
    name = "proc_run"
    value_threshold = "1.0"
    title = "Total Running Processes"
  }
  metric {
    name = "proc_total"
    value_threshold = "1.0"
    title = "Total Processes"
  }
}

/* This collection group grabs the volatile memory metrics every 40 secs and
   sends them at least every 180 secs.  This time_threshold can be increased
   significantly to reduce unneeded network traffic. */
collection_group {
  collect_every = 40
  time_threshold = 180
  metric {
    name = "mem_free"
    value_threshold = "1024.0"
    title = "Free Memory"
  }
  metric {
    name = "mem_shared"
    value_threshold = "1024.0"
    title = "Shared Memory"
  }
  metric {
    name = "mem_buffers"
    value_threshold = "1024.0"
    title = "Memory Buffers"
  }
  metric {
    name = "mem_cached"
    value_threshold = "1024.0"
    title = "Cached Memory"
  }
  metric {
    name = "swap_free"
    value_threshold = "1024.0"
    title = "Free Swap Space"
  }
}

collection_group {
  collect_every = 40
  time_threshold = 300
  metric {
    name = "bytes_out"
    value_threshold = 4096
    title = "Bytes Sent"
  }
  metric {
    name = "bytes_in"
    value_threshold = 4096
    title = "Bytes Received"
  }
  metric {
    name = "pkts_in"
    value_threshold = 256
    title = "Packets Received"
  }
  metric {
    name = "pkts_out"
    value_threshold = 256
    title = "Packets Sent"
  }
}

/* Different than 2.5.x default since the old config made no sense */
collection_group {
  collect_every = 1800
  time_threshold = 3600
  metric {
    name = "disk_total"
    value_threshold = 1.0
    title = "Total Disk Space"
  }
}

collection_group {
  collect_every = 40
  time_threshold = 180
  metric {
    name = "disk_free"
    value_threshold = 1.0
    title = "Disk Space Available"
  }
  metric {
    name = "part_max_used"
    value_threshold = 1.0
    title = "Maximum Disk Space Used"
  }
}
```

The second (this configuration came from ganglia-gmond-3.1.7, **but** from `amazon` package, they have they own package for ganglia-gmond):

```
/* This configuration is as close to 2.5.x default behavior as possible
   The values closely match ./gmond/metric.h definitions in 2.5.x */
globals {
  daemonize = yes
  setuid = yes
  user = ganglia
  debug_level = 0
  max_udp_msg_len = 1472
  mute = no
  deaf = yes
  allow_extra_data = yes
  host_dmax = 86400 /*secs */
  cleanup_threshold = 300 /*secs */
  gexec = no
  send_metadata_interval = 30 /*secs */
}

/*
 * The cluster attributes specified will be used as part of the <CLUSTER>
 * tag that will wrap all hosts collected by this instance.
 */
cluster {
  name = "DATAC2"
  owner = "Valter"
  latlong = "unspecified"
  url = ""
}

/* The host section describes attributes of the host, like the location */
host {
  location = "unspecified"
}

/* Feel free to specify as many udp_send_channels as you like.  Gmond
   used to only support having a single channel */
udp_send_channel {
  host = datac2.ganglia.valter.com
  port = 8662
  ttl = 1
}

/* You can specify as many udp_recv_channels as you like as well. */
udp_recv_channel {
  port = 8662
}

/* You can specify as many tcp_accept_channels as you like to share
   an xml description of the state of the cluster */
tcp_accept_channel {
  port = 8662
}

/* Each metrics module that is referenced by gmond must be specified and
   loaded. If the module has been statically linked with gmond, it does
   not require a load path. However all dynamically loadable modules must
   include a load path. */
modules {
  module {
    name = "core_metrics"
  }
  module {
    name = "cpu_module"
    path = "modcpu.so"
  }
  module {
    name = "disk_module"
    path = "moddisk.so"
  }
  module {
    name = "load_module"
    path = "modload.so"
  }
  module {
    name = "mem_module"
    path = "modmem.so"
  }
  module {
    name = "net_module"
    path = "modnet.so"
  }
  module {
    name = "proc_module"
    path = "modproc.so"
  }
  module {
    name = "sys_module"
    path = "modsys.so"
  }
}

include ('/etc/ganglia/conf.d/*.conf')

/* The old internal 2.5.x metric array has been replaced by the following
   collection_group directives.  What follows is the default behavior for
   collecting and sending metrics that is as close to 2.5.x behavior as
   possible. */

/* This collection group will cause a heartbeat (or beacon) to be sent every
   20 seconds.  In the heartbeat is the GMOND_STARTED data which expresses
   the age of the running gmond. */
collection_group {
  collect_once = yes
  time_threshold = 20
  metric {
    name = "heartbeat"
  }
}

/* This collection group will send general info about this host every
   1200 secs.
   This information doesn't change between reboots and is only collected
   once. */
collection_group {
  collect_once = yes
  time_threshold = 1200
  metric {
    name = "cpu_num"
    title = "CPU Count"
  }
  metric {
    name = "cpu_speed"
    title = "CPU Speed"
  }
  metric {
    name = "mem_total"
    title = "Memory Total"
  }
  /* Should this be here? Swap can be added/removed between reboots. */
  metric {
    name = "swap_total"
    title = "Swap Space Total"
  }
  metric {
    name = "boottime"
    title = "Last Boot Time"
  }
  metric {
    name = "machine_type"
    title = "Machine Type"
  }
  metric {
    name = "os_name"
    title = "Operating System"
  }
  metric {
    name = "os_release"
    title = "Operating System Release"
  }
  metric {
    name = "location"
    title = "Location"
  }
}

/* This collection group will send the status of gexecd for this host
   every 300 secs.*/
/* Unlike 2.5.x the default behavior is to report gexecd OFF. */
collection_group {
  collect_once = yes
  time_threshold = 300
  metric {
    name = "gexec"
    title = "Gexec Status"
  }
}

/* This collection group will collect the CPU status info every 20 secs.
   The time threshold is set to 90 seconds.  In honesty, this
   time_threshold could be set significantly higher to reduce
   unneccessary  network chatter. */
collection_group {
  collect_every = 20
  time_threshold = 90
  /* CPU status */
  metric {
    name = "cpu_user"
    value_threshold = "1.0"
    title = "CPU User"
  }
  metric {
    name = "cpu_system"
    value_threshold = "1.0"
    title = "CPU System"
  }
  metric {
    name = "cpu_idle"
    value_threshold = "5.0"
    title = "CPU Idle"
  }
  metric {
    name = "cpu_nice"
    value_threshold = "1.0"
    title = "CPU Nice"
  }
  metric {
    name = "cpu_aidle"
    value_threshold = "5.0"
    title = "CPU aidle"
  }
  metric {
    name = "cpu_wio"
    value_threshold = "1.0"
    title = "CPU wio"
  }
  /* The next two metrics are optional if you want more detail...
     ... since they are accounted for in cpu_system.
  metric {
    name = "cpu_intr"
    value_threshold = "1.0"
    title = "CPU intr"
  }
  metric {
    name = "cpu_sintr"
    value_threshold = "1.0"
    title = "CPU sintr"
  }
  */
}

collection_group {
  collect_every = 20
  time_threshold = 90
  /* Load Averages */
  metric {
    name = "load_one"
    value_threshold = "1.0"
    title = "One Minute Load Average"
  }
  metric {
    name = "load_five"
    value_threshold = "1.0"
    title = "Five Minute Load Average"
  }
  metric {
    name = "load_fifteen"
    value_threshold = "1.0"
    title = "Fifteen Minute Load Average"
  }
}

/* This group collects the number of running and total processes */
collection_group {
  collect_every = 80
  time_threshold = 950
  metric {
    name = "proc_run"
    value_threshold = "1.0"
    title = "Total Running Processes"
  }
  metric {
    name = "proc_total"
    value_threshold = "1.0"
    title = "Total Processes"
  }
}

/* This collection group grabs the volatile memory metrics every 40 secs and
   sends them at least every 180 secs.  This time_threshold can be increased
   significantly to reduce unneeded network traffic. */
collection_group {
  collect_every = 40
  time_threshold = 180
  metric {
    name = "mem_free"
    value_threshold = "1024.0"
    title = "Free Memory"
  }
  metric {
    name = "mem_shared"
    value_threshold = "1024.0"
    title = "Shared Memory"
  }
  metric {
    name = "mem_buffers"
    value_threshold = "1024.0"
    title = "Memory Buffers"
  }
  metric {
    name = "mem_cached"
    value_threshold = "1024.0"
    title = "Cached Memory"
  }
  metric {
    name = "swap_free"
    value_threshold = "1024.0"
    title = "Free Swap Space"
  }
}

collection_group {
  collect_every = 40
  time_threshold = 300
  metric {
    name = "bytes_out"
    value_threshold = 4096
    title = "Bytes Sent"
  }
  metric {
    name = "bytes_in"
    value_threshold = 4096
    title = "Bytes Received"
  }
  metric {
    name = "pkts_in"
    value_threshold = 256
    title = "Packets Received"
  }
  metric {
    name = "pkts_out"
    value_threshold = 256
    title = "Packets Sent"
  }
}

/* Different than 2.5.x default since the old config made no sense */
collection_group {
  collect_every = 1800
  time_threshold = 3600
  metric {
    name = "disk_total"
    value_threshold = 1.0
    title = "Total Disk Space"
  }
}

collection_group {
  collect_every = 40
  time_threshold = 180
  metric {
    name = "disk_free"
    value_threshold = 1.0
    title = "Disk Space Available"
  }
  metric {
    name = "part_max_used"
    value_threshold = 1.0
    title = "Maximum Disk Space Used"
  }
}
```

Using [meld](http://meldmerge.org/) I saw that  the difference aren't much, but enough to don't make my application to run, so that's why I can't make the same `.conf` file. But I could use a template for this.
But how can I do that ?
Because it's not some variable that differs from one file to another, but adding/removing some lines, and that's where I stuck.

Any idea, suggestion ?

Comment: Please provide some example with some adding/removing diff. Current files differs only in variables.

Comment: I would provide the diff, but I dont't understand the diff very well, I use meld for that, but I couldn't figure an intuitive way to put it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with diff:

```
--- gmond.amazon    2013-05-14 23:00:23.534421793 +0400
+++ gmond.rpmforge  2013-05-14 22:59:21.614420963 +0400
@@ -20,7 +20,7 @@
  * tag that will wrap all hosts collected by this instance.
  */
 cluster {
-  name = "DATAC2"
+  name = "DATAC1"
   owner = "Valter"
   latlong = "unspecified"
   url = ""
@@ -34,20 +34,20 @@
 /* Feel free to specify as many udp_send_channels as you like.  Gmond
    used to only support having a single channel */
 udp_send_channel {
-  host = datac2.ganglia.valter.com
-  port = 8662
+  host = datac1.ganglia.valter.com
+  port = 8660
   ttl = 1
 }

 /* You can specify as many udp_recv_channels as you like as well. */
 udp_recv_channel {
-  port = 8662
+  port = 8660
 }

 /* You can specify as many tcp_accept_channels as you like to share
    an xml description of the state of the cluster */
 tcp_accept_channel {
-  port = 8662
+  port = 8660
 }
```

So `gmond.conf.erb` template could be something like that (missing the equal parts of the
files):

```
cluster {
  name = "<%=@cluster[:name]%>"
  owner = "Valter"
  latlong = "unspecified"
  url = ""
}

/* The host section describes attributes of the host, like the location */
host {
  location = "unspecified"
}

/* Feel free to specify as many udp_send_channels as you like.  Gmond
   used to only support having a single channel */
udp_send_channel {
  name = <%=@udp_send_channel[:name]%>
  port = <%=@udp_send_channel[:port]%>
  ttl = 1
}

/* You can specify as many udp_recv_channels as you like as well. */
udp_recv_channel {
  port = <%=@udp_recv_channel[:port]%>
}

/* You can specify as many tcp_accept_channels as you like to share
   an xml description of the state of the cluster */
tcp_accept_channel {
  port = <%=@tcp_accept_channel[:port]%>
}
```

It could be called like

```rb
template "/etc/whatever/gmond.conf" do
  source "gmond.conf.erb"
  mode 0644
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  variables({
    :cluster => {
      :name => "something"
    },
    :udp_send_channel => {
      :name => "name",
      :port => 1234
    },
    :udp_recv_channel => {
      :port => 2345
    },
    :tcp_accept_channel => {
      :port => 3456
    }
  })
end
```